# Repetition of preposition

Tags: prepositions

Is it necessary to repeat preposition in the following sentence   .the books on the table and on the desk are mine.

Answer (score -1):

You would not need to repeat the preposition. It would be better said like this:  'The books on the table and the desk are mine.' or 'The books on the table and desk are mine.'. Hope this helps.

Comment: This could possibly confuse the listener to believe that the desk is yours.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco It's highly unlikely any native speaker would make that assumption.